# 16 GB Sandisk SD card is 14.4 GB and not 14.8 GB

Tags: memory, sd-card

I have two SanDisk 16 GB SD cards, but when I look at the size the second one (the one I just bought) is not as big as the old one.

[image]
(Disk 2 is the new SD card and disk 3 is the old one)

The problem is I have a 16 GB image for my RPi3 that cannot fit on the new one, and a backup of my old SD card can't fit either.

I tried using SanDisk's [suggestion to reformat the card](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14827/~/using-sd-formatter-tool-to-restore-full-capacity-on-sdhc%2Fsdxc-cards) but that didn't change anything.

How can I get the 14.8 GB capacity of my old SD card?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you see one is FAT16 and the other is FAT32?

Comment: I tried formatting it to all kinds filesystems, and its always 14.4gb

Comment: Have you checked the raw number of bytes/blocks available on the cards?  Do they match and it is a formatting issue or is their physically less "space" on one vs the other?

Comment: Are the sector size the same? You may have one with 4k sector size and the other with 8k, or some other detail that makes them different

Comment: @Damon added some more screenshots using EaseUS partition master

Answer (score 0):

Your physical sectors are differing.  The smaller card has 797696 less sectors.  At an assumed 512 bytes per sector that would be or approximately 408MB or 0.4GB which is very close to your current size difference of 0.38GB.

Comment: And why does it have that, they are the same model bought a year a part

Comment: @Mech0z That would be a question for the manufacturer.